# How to get all tab attributes values of all element from .bpmn file?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

Am new to camunda as well as java.
My requirement is, I want to get all attributes value from all node of every task, event, Gateway… etc through java and transfer to excel file in seperate sheet.

I have tried to code using Read a model document, but cant get exact output.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        File file = new File("My file path/My_model.bpmn");
        BpmnModelInstance modelInstance = Bpmn.readModelFromFile(file);
        
        // find all elements of the type task
        ModelElementType taskType = modelInstance.getModel().getType(Task.class);
        Collection<ModelElementInstance> taskInstances = modelInstance.getModelElementsByType(taskType);
        
        System.out.println(taskType.getByName());
    }
}
```

I know it contain nothing much.
Please guide my from the scratch, that how can I achieve my code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which attributes you want to access there may be different ways of accessing them. This example should help: https://github.com/rob2universe/bpmn-creator/blob/master/src/main/java/DataMappings.java

e.g.

```
  modelInst.getModelElementsByType(FlowNode.class).forEach(e ->
  {
    log.info("{} : {} : {}", e.getName(), e.getId(), e.getElementType().getTypeName());
    log.info("Attribute completionQuantity: {}", e.getAttributeValue("completionQuantity"));
  });

  modelInst.getModelElementsByType(CamundaInputParameter.class).forEach(e ->
  {
    // may need to guard this more
    UserTask userTask = (UserTask) e.getParentElement().getParentElement().getParentElement();
    log.info("Parent {} has input {} with value {}", userTask.getId(), e.getCamundaName(), e.getTextContent());
  });

  modelInst.getModelElementsByType(CamundaOutputParameter.class).forEach(e ->
  {
    // may need to guard this more
    UserTask userTask = (UserTask) e.getParentElement().getParentElement().getParentElement();
    log.info("Parent {} has input {} with value {}", userTask.getId(), e.getCamundaName(), e.getTextContent());
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But if I want to get all configured property values from all tabs (General, Listeners, I/O, Field Injection) for all tasks means, how can I achieve it. From this example code I can get some of the property values only. Please suggest some ideas to achieve my requirement.

Comment: You need to see for each tab how the values are stored in the XML. They get stored in different attributes and tags and are access differently via API. Properties, extension attributes, data mappings,... When you look at the objects in the result set in the debugger then you can also easily see where the info is stored. Give it a shot first. If you have a specific thing you cannot get then let me know.